# WordPress Monthly Archive by Year

Tags: wordpress, archive

WordPress extraordinaires, I need your help!

I need to be able to list the archives, but in a slightly different way than the WP codex, or an hour of Googling will show me.

I need the months of the year, as the generic archive function, but only for one year at a time.
So, list all the months in 2007. I'll need to be able to use this multiple times in the same template too, for different years.
I've got a feeling query_posts might be the way, but I'm not too sure.

Anyone got some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the Wordpress Codex

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly'); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I meant.
I need it to display the months under it too, but only for one year.

Comment: Hmm. You could use wp_get_archives with format=custom and echo=0, then parse through it to remove all but the required year?

Comment: (Sorry for the 11 day delay in replying!)

I tried this too, but no luck. We've decided to go another way anyway, but a solution would still be good to know for the future.